# What is this warped/ irregular rectangle in this mobile app UI?

Tags: interface-design, mobile

What is the name of this effect present on the rectangle (e.g. light brown rectangle), and how is it done? The rectangle does not have a constant border radius, and gives a 'fun'/ friendly feeling.

[image]

I took it from Dribble, available [here](https://dribbble.com/shots/14858049-Bill-Splitter-App/attachments/6568109?mode=media).

Here is my funky analysis:
[image]

Comment: I suspect it's **not** that light brown rectangle.. it's the dark purple shape with rounded corners. ... and I do not believe there's any specific name for such a shape. It could be said the brown magnifying glass shape is "inset".

Comment: I added a circle to show that its not a constant border radius. I think almost all the rectangles have this effect

Comment: Ahh.. I was looking at the wrong thing `:)` I think that's just a border radius.. I don't know why you seem to feel it's more than that. It's [pretty even](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ8rq.png) in my view.

Comment: @Scott The central part of the rounding is even, but the sides do not ‘swing back’ to 0°/90° immediately after that rounding – if you removed the rounded corner that you highlighted in your image, you wouldn’t be left with a regular rectangle, but with a slightly bulging one. It’s an interesting effect, but I don’t know if a word for it. ‘Bulging rectangle with rounded corners’ is how I’d describe it.

Comment: hmmm.. seems to me to simply be a [% for rounding](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/kctsqyz3/4/) rather than a hard integer. % will cause *more* of the rounding to appear to be on the longer edge. I, honestly, [see no "bulging"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpBNN.png) (beyond image anti-aliasing). All I see are rounded corners. So perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Turns out even the iPhone doesn't use a constant border radius: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313713/what-is-the-definitive-iphone-x-corner-radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific name for this kind of shape, however you could do something similar with Bézier curves in almost any vector software.

Start with a normal rounded rectangle (i.e. rounded by radius), and pull the Bézier handles out horizontally and vertically, perhaps using a grid to make sure it's exact, and repeat for each corner.

This example was made in Inkscape, but the same is possible in Illustrator and other vector software.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great :). now I just need to figure out how to do it in Flutter. 

Comment: @BenButterworth Flutter doesn't seem to be a vector image editor as far as I can tell.  Inkscape is free and Open Source. You can export images as SVG or PNG